# PDF reader with inverted colors or invert colors only on one app?

Tags: colors, osx-yosemite, pdf-reader

I'm new to OSX and  have a copy of OSX Yosemite.

I really like iBooks and Preview, but I need a night theme or the option to invert colors as in Linux with Gnome's Document Viewer.

I'm aware that I can globally invert colors through accessibility options, but my goal is to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> a book and be able to write code. Global invert colors would mess up my text editor color scheme, terminal colors and many more.

So, does anyone know another way to achieve this inverted color effect for PDF viewing? I'm open to using a different PDF reader if it has the option to invert colors or any other method that allows me to invert colors only for Preview/iBooks.

Comment: You invert the *file* and use any viewer; [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/invert-colors-in-whole-pdf-convertion/201737#201737) was written for GNU/Linux but may work on OSX.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks! Sounds like a good idea and doable if it's Ruby.

Comment: Good luck! Oh, I notice I miswrote there, it's actually a bash script. :/ It would probably be cleaner and easier to adapt if I had used Ruby. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out here: **system preferences > keyboard section > shortcuts**

There is a list of shortcuts the order depends on the apps, you'll have to look for "invert colors" and activate it (check the box).
Beware, they change it's name at each version of OSX, you'll probably find it under the "accessibility" subsection of shortcuts.

They don't change the shortcut, you should look for this combination:
**cmd + alt + ctrl + 8**

Once you activate it you can bind any key combination you like, just check it is not already being used. Use this shortcut to toggle from normal to inverted.

This works in all apps, but it's quite easy to go from normal to inverted with shortcuts.